# How can I get the bit depth/sample rate of audio JS?

Tags: javascript, audio, audiocontext, sample-rate, bit-depth

I need to get the Sample Rate of Audio file, loaded by standard input element. 
I tried to use this function

```
function func(e) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function(event) {
            let buffer = reader.result;
            let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
            let context = new AudioContext();
            context.decodeAudioData(buffer, function(buffer1) {
                    console.log(buffer1.sampleRate);
                });
            }
        }
```

But it always displays one incorrect answer 48000 regardless of file.

So I try to calculate the Sample Rate with formula

```
SampleRate = File.size/(NumberOfChannels*BitDepth*File.duration);
```

But I dont know how to get the value of audio BitDepth. Please, help.

Comment: did you try to see if sampleRate is an attribute on your reader object ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont see sampleRate as attribute of reader. Is it?

Comment: Web Audio API cannot change sample rate ...  does your audio render sounding too fast or too slow ?   a typical bit depth for CD quality audio is 16   ... baked into web audio api is notion of channels ... try using a known mono audio file to simplify ...  what audio codec is your input file ?

Comment: @ScottStensland I dont need to change sample rate and to render sound, I need to display sample rate on web site after file loading. The difficulty is that the file can be any.