# How to fetch 'Audio Channels', 'Sample rate', 'Bits per sample' of a .wav file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am trying to display 'Audio Channels', 'Sample rate', 'Bits per sample' of an audio file using javascript when user has selected the file that needs to be uploaded.

In the image below see 'more_info' part:

[image]

As of now I have tried to get the details using file properties but it gives only basic information like size, type, name

I have also tried this but same issue of same sample rate [How can I get the bit depth/sample rate of audio JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181897/how-can-i-get-the-bit-depth-sample-rate-of-audio-js)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)